# Can MS Office Access 2010 lock a record at the time it is created?

Tags: sql-server, vba, transactions, locking

We use a MS Office Access 2010 database application for permit tracking and payment processing.  The application includes forms with underlying VBA code for the convenience of the administrative staff responsible for the collection of fees and printing receipts.

In order to make the transactional data more ledger-like and auditable, we'd like to have the ability to lock a record at the moment the transaction receipt is printed.  By the way, we have other Access applications that house the majority of the table data in a MS SQL Server 2008 R2 database so, all or part of the answer might be to push the data for this application out to that table set.

I've looked at the MS Office Access 2010 > Options > Client Settings > Advanced > Default Record Locking, but I don't think that's the answer for this process.

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated!  vtgarnerTCTO

Answer (score 0):

afaik it's not programmatically possible to 'lock' a single record to prevent future edits, so your options are..

1  Create a column named something like IsLocked (yes/no), where 1=locked, and everywhere in your app prevent any edits where IsLocked = 1.  The weakness here is that editing can happen outside of this programming.

2  Create two tables:  Stuff_Locked and Stuff_unlocked (rename to whatever floats your boat).  Users enter data into Stuff_unlocked, and once you deem a record to be locked then programmatically insert into Stuff_locked / delete from Stuff_unlocked.  Stuff_locked is read only except for the above programmatic insert.

Obviously neither option is low-maintenance, but those are your options..